# Inherited Interfaces In C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

In c sharp abstract methods must be implemented by child class. So my question is when an interface inherits another interface why doesn't it implement all of base interface members.

```
public interface IShape
{
  void Points();
}
public interface ICircle: IShape
{
  void IsDrawAble();
}
```

When i run this program in Visual Studio 2010 and no error came up. By definition ICircle must implement Points function.

Thanks

Comment: Interfaces don't have any implementation.

Comment: `Abstract` classes can avoid interface implementation either. You just need to declare the methods and mark them `abstract`.

Comment: Interface is not a class. Call it a Contract that class abides to.

Comment: Don't think of interface inheritance as inheritance. (I wish the spec had chosen a different word.) Think of it instead as meaning "a struct or class which implements this interface is required to also implement that interface".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interfaces don't implement *anything*.

An interface simply contains a list of members that concrete classes need to implement.
There would be no point in re-declaring members that were already required by a base interface.

Similarly, an `abstract` class that inherits another `abstract` class (or interface) does not need to implement any of its methods.

Comment: Nit picky point: even an abstract class must provide an implementation of all its interface members, but an abstract class is allowed to give an abstract implementation.  That is, `interface I { void M(); } abstract class C : I {} ` is illegal, but `abstract class C : I { public abstract void M(); }` is legal.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks; I vaguely remembered that.  Why, BTW?

Comment: @SLaks: If a class claims to implement an interface, .NET requires that every interface member must be mapped to a member of that class.  If C# were to implicitly declare a public abstract virtual method, that would force derived classes to make their implementation public.  If it were to declare a protected abstract virtual method, that would prevent derived classes from making their implementation public.

Answer (score 2):

When you implement `ICircle` you'll need to implement `Points()` as well. The following code does not compile:

```
class MyClass : ICircle
{
    void IsDrawAble() { }
}
```

So what you stated should be : "By definition all implementations of ICircle must implement the IShape members as well"

Comment: It does compile thats why i asked this question because by definition ICircle must implement Points but it didn't and VS didn't throw any error. But i just understood if all interfaces implement base class methods than class that implement that interface will implement same method twice.

Comment: The interfaces alone compile; my example in combination with your interfaces does not compile. `ICircle : IShape` means anyone who implements `ICircle` must implement `IShape` too.

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question yourself. **Because it's an interface**. Interfaces are not classes, therefore they don't have to (in fact cannot) implement other interfaces they inherit.

Answer (score 0):

When you create this kind of hierarchy between interfaces, you are defining who implement the `Circle` interface will also implement `IShape`. So, for sample:

```
public class Test : ICircle
{
   public void Points()
   {
      // some code
   }

   public void IsDrawAble()
   {
      // some code
   }

}
```

Using it:

```
ICircle obj = new Test();
obj.Points();
obj.IsDrawAble();
```

or

```
IShape obj = new Test();
obj.Points();
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface represents a *contract*. They contain only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers. An interface doesn't implement at all. A class/struct that implements an interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.

The hierarchy you have created simply means that whatever implements the `ICircle` interface also implements the `IShape` interface.